# How to append files in GCS with the same schema?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way one can append two files in GCS, suppose file one is a full 
  load and second file is an incremental load. Then what's the way we can append 
  the two?
  Secondly, using gsutil compose will append the two files including the attributes 
  names as well. So, in the final file I want the data of the two files.

Comment: Please ask one question at once.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to stackoverflow..will surely keep it in mind moving forward!

Answer (score 0):

You can append two separate files [using `compose`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) in the Google Cloud Shell and rename the output file as the first file, like this:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/obj1
```

This command is meant for parallel uploads in which you divide a large object file in smaller objects. They get uploaded to Google Cloud Storage and then you can append them to get the original file. You can find more information on [Composite Objects and Parallel Uploads.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects)

I've come up with two possible solutions:

### Google Cloud Function solution

The option I would go for is using a Cloud Function. Doing something like the following:

1. Create an empty bucket like append_bucket.
2. Upload the first file.
3. Create a Cloud Function to be [triggered by new uploaded files](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-tabs) on the
   bucket.
4. Upload the second file.
5. Read the first and the second file (you will have to [download them as string](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_string) first).
6. Make the append operation.
7. Upload the result to the bucket.

### Google Dataflow solution

You can also do it with [Dataflow for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery) (keep in mind it’s still in beta).

1. Create a BigQuery dataset and table.
2. Create a Dataflow instance, from the template Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery.
3. Create a Javascript file with the logic to transform the text.
4. Upload your files in Json format to the bucket.
5. Dataflow will read the Json file, execute the Javascript code and append the new data to the BigQuery dataset.
6. At last, export the BigQuery query result to Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply.But the first approach will only work if the file size is below 10 MB,as cloud functions are having the limitations in terms of data processing. But if the case was just to move the file from one bucket to another then there is no size limitation.

Comment: @flametech Yes, it's true that Cloud Functions has some limitations, that is why I provided other options so you are aware of possible solutions that are available on GCP. Nonetheless, did my answer help you?

Comment: There is a tool named Attunity compose which can be used for merging the files and providing the result in one final target file, which can be used as an external source for fetching the data using BQ.Both the above answers are correct in order to provide the solution, but have certain limitations 1) in terms of data processing 2) pricing issue. So, keeping both these constraints in mind, Attunity Compose works well.